# How to disable inherited annotations on Mockito mocks?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-aop

I have a class with a @Transactional function, which I'm interested in creating mocks for. The issue is that this annotation is inherited, so calling the function on the mocks causes Spring AOP to try starting a transaction, which makes the tests fail. Is there any way to disable the annotation on the mock function?
Thanks!

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Please provide your code (test, class, and the full exception you get).

Comment: You can probably adjust the pointcuts to not include your test code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.